# How to log into Windows 10 using keyboard only

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, login

How can I log into Windows 10 from sleep using only the keyboard?

Currently:

1. I tap a key and the computer wakes from sleep.  It shows me a lovely vista of some place I've never been.
2. The keyboard does nothing.  I must first click the mouse button, presumably to give the login screen the focus.  (Really?)
3. I can now press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to remove the photo and see the username/password prompt.
4. I type my password and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

It's having to switch to the mouse in step 2 the frustrates me.  Is there another way to get the username/password prompt without leaving the keyboard?

Comment: you should be able to hit any key to get the logon prompt, if not something isnt right

Comment: I have the same issue. Want to login with keyboard only. But force to click once with mouse so that login/PIN prompt appears.

Comment: Still an issue after latest round of updates. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> first will give the window focus.  Then any of the usual keys will bring up the login prompt.

Comment: This worked for me. I can confirm pressing`ESC` does nothing. Still kind of shocked that the issue was that **nothing** was in focus! Sometimes Windows is stupid. :P Thanks for finding this! It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

Press `ESC` - that will reveal the login fields.

Comment: Nope, it won't respond to that either.